# Installing NuGet Package for Breeze.WebApi2.EF6 1.4.11 - Dependency Not Compatible

Tags: breeze, nuget-package

I'm working in VS2013 with an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with EF6.  When I try to install the Breeze NuGet package, I get an error and the install is rolled back.  I'm wondering what action I can take to get the package to install.  Here's the output info:

```
------- Installing...Breeze.WebApi2.EF6 1.4.11 -------
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.Client (= 1.4.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Q'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2 (= 1.4.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData (≥ 5.0 && < 6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.0.0 && < 5.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.6.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.6.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 5.0 && < 6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.1.2 && < 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider (= 1.4.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebActivator'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6 (= 1.4.11)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 6.0 && < 7.0)'.
Installing 'Q 1.0.0'.
Added file 'q.js' to folder 'Q.1.0.0\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'q.min.js' to folder 'Q.1.0.0\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'Q.1.0.0.nuspec' to folder 'Q.1.0.0'.
Added file 'Q.1.0.0.nupkg' to folder 'Q.1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'Q 1.0.0'.
Installing 'Breeze.Client 1.4.11'.
Added file 'breeze.debug.js' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'breeze.intellisense.js' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'breeze.min.js' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'readme.txt' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Added file 'install.ps1' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11\tools'.
Added file 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.Client 1.4.11'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.1.2'.
Added file 'System.Web.Http.OData.dll' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2\lib\net45'.
Added file 'System.Web.Http.OData.xml' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2\lib\net45'.
Added file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2.nuspec' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2'.
Added file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2.nupkg' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 5.1.2'.
Installing 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider 1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.ContextProvider.dll' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11\lib'.
Added file 'readme.txt' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider 1.4.11'.
Installing 'WebActivator 1.5.3'.
Added file 'WebActivator.dll' to folder 'WebActivator.1.5.3\lib\net40'.
Added file 'WebActivator.1.5.3.nuspec' to folder 'WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Added file 'WebActivator.1.5.3.nupkg' to folder 'WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Successfully installed 'WebActivator 1.5.3'.
Installing 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2 1.4.11'.
Added file 'BreezeWebApiConfig.cs.pp' to folder 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\content\App_Start'.
Added file 'Breeze.WebApi2.dll' to folder 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\lib'.
Added file 'readme.txt' to folder 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2 1.4.11'.
Installing 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6 1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.dll' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11\lib'.
Added file 'readme.txt' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6 1.4.11'.
Installing 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6 1.4.11'.
Added file 'readme.txt' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Added file 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6 1.4.11'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Removed file 'q.js' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0\content\Scripts'.
Removed file 'q.min.js' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0\content\Scripts'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0\content\Scripts'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0\content'.
Removed file 'Q.1.0.0.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0'.
Removed file 'Q.1.0.0.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Q.1.0.0'.
Removed file 'breeze.debug.js' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Removed file 'breeze.intellisense.js' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Removed file 'breeze.min.js' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content\Scripts'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\content'.
Removed file 'install.ps1' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\tools'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11\tools'.
Removed file 'readme.txt' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Client.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Client.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'System.Web.Http.OData.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2\lib\net45'.
Removed file 'System.Web.Http.OData.xml' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2\lib\net45'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2\lib\net45'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2\lib'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.5.1.2'.
Removed file 'Breeze.ContextProvider.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11\lib'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11\lib'.
Removed file 'readme.txt' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'WebActivator.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3\lib\net40'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3\lib\net40'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3\lib'.
Removed file 'WebActivator.1.5.3.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Removed file 'WebActivator.1.5.3.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Removed file 'BreezeWebApiConfig.cs.pp' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\content\App_Start'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\content\App_Start'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\content'.
Removed file 'Breeze.WebApi2.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\lib'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11\lib'.
Removed file 'readme.txt' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.WebApi2.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11\lib'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11\lib'.
Removed file 'readme.txt' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'readme.txt' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed file 'Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\Christopher\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BrookfieldCO_WebApp\packages\Breeze.WebApi2.EF6.1.4.11'.
Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.1.2' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.
==============================
```

Comment: What project template are you using? I noticed in the log 2 conflicting dependencies, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.0.0 && < 5.1) and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.1.2 && < 5.2.0).

Comment: I used the "Ignite UI MVC 5 (Razor)" from the Infragistics 2014.1 IgniteUI release that came out on 4/21/14.

Comment: Can you find out if that project template imposes the following restriction, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.0.0 && < 5.1) or (≥ 5.1.2 && < 5.2.0) ?

Comment: Denis,it appears not as I only find a ...WebApi.Core in the packages.config showing 5.0.0.0.  However, your question prompted me to look at the IgniteUI template by creating  new project and exporting as a template.  Then I decided to try installing your Breeze NuGet package on the fresh project and it installed fine.  I guess it was my install of NuGet packages for Glimpse MVC 5 and Glimpse EF6 or my update of Newtonsoft.Json to 6.0.3 that got references in a twist.  I may start over from scratch and get Breeze installed early.  Thanks much for your help!